# How to get years from a time series index when the underlying time series is of monthly freq?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I´d like to extract years from a time series index (the underlying time series is of monthly frequency). The reason I want to do it is creating a yearly axis, e.g.

```
plot(myts)
axis(1, at = year(time(myts)), labels = FALSE)
# note I know 'year()' does not work :)
```

because if I just plot it, R arbitrarily(?) creates a time axis. Often it's a two or even 5 year axis which makes is inappropriate sometimes.

```
tsp(myts) 
[1] 1966.000 1974.917   12.000
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your time series: perhaps just show output from `tsp(myts)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an own solution. Maybe this helps someone else, too. Besides I think it's not overly smart... so I am looking forward to your suggestions.

```
 axis(1, at = start(time(myts))[1]:end(time(myts))[1], labels = TRUE)
```

EDIT: found a more elegant solution:

```
require(zoo)
x <- as.yearqtr("1991 Q1")
format.Date(x,"%Y")
```

according to @matty T pain it also works for `ts` (see comments).

Comment: Have you found anything better than this? I upvoted because I can't find anything at all. Some complex things in R are so simple, yet some simple stuff like this is super verbose and hard to do.

Comment: wow, that was I while ago but your comment made me look at it again. And looks like I just found a better way to extract years: `x <- as.yearqtr("1991 Q1")` then use `format.Date(x,"%Y")`. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: ah, i realize `as.yearqtr` is `zoo`, but guess it should work for `ts` as well.

Comment: yes, just tried that on a ts and it works exactly as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your data, but if it is a time series class (ts), then you can use the **window** function:

`window(myts,start="*beginyear*",end="*endyear*")`

If you cannot do that, maybe you can use some of the suggestions here:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Year-and-Month-extraction-from-Date-object-td904011.html

Matt

Comment: window gives back the data, not the index.