# Adding points to xts plot

Tags: r, graphics, xts, zoo, quantmod

I thought [Adding Points, Legends and Text to plots using xts objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021413/adding-points-legends-and-text-to-plots-using-xts-objects) would have the answer to this question, but apparently not...

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("SAM")
big.red.dot <- zoo(85, as.Date("2011-05-05"))
plot(SAM['2011'])
points(  big.red.dot, col="red", pch=19, cex=5  )
```

This one seems to be straight out of the textbook. `?plot.zoo` doesn't contain any examples with `point()` though.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich Thank you for correcting the title (and writing the package!). The sequence of title edits make it clear that I don't understand the difference between `plot.zoo`, `plot.xts`, and "`quantmod` plot", if the last one exists. Could you point me to a reference please?

Comment: @Lau Tzu: `plot` is a generic function.  `plot.zoo` and `plot.xts` are simply methods for zoo and xts class objects.  See `?plot.zoo` and `?plot.xts` for descriptions of each respective function.  quantmod has the `chartSeries` plotting function.

Comment: @isomorphismes I should have looked at `Methods(plot)` as well to understand how `plot` (the generic one) works. Also http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the objects created by `quantmod::getSymbols` are in fact of class `xts`. This means your `big.red.dot` should be a `xts` object:

```
big.red.dot <- xts(85, as.Date("2011-05-05"))
plot(SAM['2011'])
points(  big.red.dot, col="red", pch=19, cex=5  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm not surprised the answer was so obvious.